# How to send C2DM Registration ID to server

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I've scoured the internet for a while now and I cannot get my Android app to send the registration ID and device ID to the server. I'm sure there is something simple that I am missing, but can anyone see what I am doing wrong? The code is hit and the Toasts are shown, but the server doesn't do anything, but if I go to the URL directly, it does what I want it to.

```
if (!regId.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "The registration ID is: " + regId,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(context, "The device ID is: " + deviceId,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://uni.britintel.co.uk/register.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceId", deviceId));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registrationId", regId));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpresponse.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("HttpResponse", line);
                Toast.makeText(context, line,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "The registration ID doesn't exist",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

The buffered reader will be removed once I get it working as it is pointless for what I want.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I tried to use GET instead of POST, but it still doesn't want to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to get it to work.

I added the following permissions to the manifest xml, but not sure why it fixed it...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

There were also some issues with my server, but I only got a response after adding the permissions.